# how to check n splitted string are exist (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

i just want to ask how to check the n splitted string are exist or not?

For the example :
input is a TextBox and I put a text in the TextBox "hi there"

```
var TEXTS = input.Text.Split(' ');
```

we know that the result is :
TEXTS[0] = "hi"
TEXTS[1] = "there"

I want to check are the TEXTS[1] is exist?

I just tried like this but its not working.

```
if (TEXTS[1]!=null) {

}
```

Comment: TEXTS.Length >= 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the index of array exists by using the following code:

```
int index = 25 ;  //input any number here

if(index < array.Length)
{
    //it exists
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Its simple and exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve the same result as the other answers by using the `System.Linq` namespace for slightly nicer looking syntax.

```
if (TEXTS.ElementAtOrDefault(1) != null){
    Console.Write("IT EXISTS!!");
}
```

Comment: `TEXTS[0].Any()` actually means that `TEXTS[0]` string is *not empty*; or put it diferently, `input.Text` *doesn't start* with space

Comment: Yeah - that's what we want isn't it?

Comment: "I want to check are the TEXTS[1] is exist?" it can be treated as "TEXTS has at least 2 items" (my interpretation, i.e. we can *address* `TEXTS[1]` *safely*) or if you want "TEXTS[1] is not empty"; in this case, please, notice the index: `1`

Comment: You're right, my bad. I've updated the answer to include another which uses the `System.Linq` namespace

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the length of the array like:

```
if (TEXTS.Length > 1) { }
```

Comment: It's a correct implementation; however `1` is a magic value and thus difficult to digest. `TEXTS.Length >= 2` is, IMHO, a slightly better choice: when we want `2` items we compare with `2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` to get each value

```
var TEXTS = input.Text.Split(' ');
foreach (string val in TEXTS)
{
//you can use val
}
```

or you can you `for` to get each value

```
var TEXTS = input.Text.Split(' ');
for (int i = 0; i < TEXTS.Length; i++)
{
//you can use TEXTS[i]
}
```

I hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *check only*, all you have to do is to *count separators* (spaces, in the context):

```
int count = 2; // we want to ensure at least 2 items

bool result = input
  .Text
  .Where(c => c == ' ')
  .Skip(count - 2)
  .Any();

if (result) {
  // we have at least count - 1 spaces, and thus at least count parts
}
```

If you want to *split* and *check*, try using `Length`:

```
int count = 2; // we want to ensure at least 2 items

string[] items = input
  .Text
  .Split(' ');

if (items.Length >= count) {
  // we have at least count items, and thus can put items[0] ... items[count - 1]
}
```